# Oracle Sql: How do I avoid double occurrence in the result?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables:
table **emp** (a part of it):

```
ID|LAST_NAME
------------
12|Giljum
14|Nguyen
```

and **ord** (also only required information):

```
ID |SALES_REP_ID
---------------
101|14
106|12
97 |12
98 |14
99 |14
```

I need to find the last names of employees that have handled the orders that have an id below 100.
So i tried this:

```
SELECT E.last_name 
FROM emp E,ord O
WHERE E.id = O.sales_rep_id 
AND O.id < 100;
```

And the result is:

```
LAST_NAME
---------
Giljum
Nguyen
Nguyen
```

And my question is, how to avoid the double occurrence of Nguyen, if possible without using a subquery.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with the DISTINCT operator:

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.last_name 
FROM emp E,ord O
WHERE E.id = O.sales_rep_id 
AND O.id < 100;
```

Comment: Oh, i totally forgot about that :D, thanks for help